# Ubuntu 13.04 wont shut down?

Tags: 13.04, shutdown

My 32 bit OEM 1 gb ram wont shut down after I select 'shut down' from the drop box on the right top corner. Also, when I press the power button on the notebook nothing happens.
Help? The machine shuts down / restarts properly when the command prompt is used, 'suspends' then restarts after a few seconds: the output while in suspend contains a few errors:

```
device already exists
cannot hot-add device
Link training error
USB `1-3 device descriptor read 8 (read 64) error
failed to check link status
```

There is additional code headings that can be referenced if need be.
The option to restart also is missing from the contents of the right hand top corner drop box. The initial error I did get twice on startup was that the software center had to 'close unexpectedly'.

Comment: Try using the command line `sudo shutdown -r 0` for and tell us what messages you see. (That's like hitting "restart").

Comment: What kind of laptop do you have?

Comment: its an OEM Durabook Intel® Pentium(R) Dual CPU T3200 @ 2.00GHz × 2

Comment: is there a way to pause the shutdown long enough to read the output in the black shutdown screen?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall unity, This works on most cases, and it is reliable because you wont lose anything if something wrong happens ;)

Which drivers have you installed? and services (like apache) they may wont work properly on 13.04, write them so I check them myself and tell you if they have any problems on 13.04 ;)

EDIT: Does synaptic or apt-get commands give you errors?

Comment: ... It restarts and shuts down using the terminal shell without errors

Comment: I guess this is about unity, I've never felt that unity is a stable DE, have you tried reinstalling it?
Do you have other desktop environments? do they have the same issue?

Comment: initially I installed the unity tool and I have since removed it. the situation is unchanged

Comment: runserver/sqlite is not working either

Comment: Do you mean Unity Tweak Tool? Did you mess with Unity settings?

Comment: no I did not 'mess' with the settings.

Answer (score 0):

this could be caused by a permission issue.

my firefox wouldn't start from the launcher, but it starts from the terminal. do this and see if shutdown worksa after:

```
$ chown -hR $USER .gnome2/
$ chown -hR $USER .gnome2_private/
```

Comment: maybe its a permission issue or maybe its Unity but that code didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following recently to solve this problem of SHUTDOWN and automatic REBOOT again withing a second or two.

I have Intel Visual BIOS. On power up I pressed F2 > POWER > Wake On LAN from S4/S5.

This has 3 options. 1. Stay Off, 2. Power on - Normal Boot, and 3. Power on - PXE Boot. My computer was set to #2, which was making it automatically REBOOT after SHUTDOWN. I now changed to #1 option mentioned above. Now it is okay.